# Android/Gradle: how to find the good mix of Google dependencies versions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have often compiling errors due to the versions of the different Google dependencies that have bad interactions between them.

Typical gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.22.1.0'
```

At the end, the project doesn't compile with an error like this:

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':XXX:preDebugBuild'.
    > In project 'XXX' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1
      5.0.1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

      Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
      15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

      The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
      ifact with the issue.
      -- Project 'XXX' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@16.0.0
      -- Project 'XXX' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics@16.0.1
      -- Project 'XXX' depends onto com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk@4.22.1
      -- Project 'XXX' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@17.1.1
      -- Project 'XXX' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.1
      -- Project 'XXX' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.1.0

      For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :XXX:assembleDebug to see the
       dependency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at http
      s://github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to yo
      ur build.gradle file.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 25s
```

How to solve this kind of issue with a reliable methodology ? (with the goal to have the latest possible version for each lib)

Comment: hey, how did you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to your Log file

```
 Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
      15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.
```

Its problem occurred due to different version of `Google Play Service`.

To resolve these kind of problems in android define a constant version in `gradle.properties` file

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true
COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=26
BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
TARGET_SDK_VERSION=26
MIN_SDK_VERSION=17
ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=26.1.0
PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION=16.0.1
```

To use these constant in `build.gradle(Module:app)` define like below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION as String}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION as String}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION as String}"

}
```

Similarly you can define others library like firebase or others.

Comment: Thanks but when I put my mouse over for example play-services-analytics and play-services-ads, I see that these two libs can be updated to the last version but both versions are not the same ones. Which one should I choose ?

Comment: version not differ, you can choose any one for both, or simple use "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION as String}" and remove specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straight answer to your question.

My recommendation would be to use `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0` since it should also include both `play-services-analytics` and `play-services-ads` which can then be removed. And then keeping an eye on the [release versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) of your libraries every two weeks.

Yes, I know, this is probably not the answer you were looking for, but on the long run, it will give you less headaches.

---

If that's not enough to convince you, there is another way of reducing the amount of time it takes to keep the versions up to date using `+` in the minor version number (for instance `16.0.+` instead of `16.0.0`).

**WARNING:** Automatically increasing the version numbers **could lead to issues** (i.e.: different versions resolved in your CI and your local machine, unexpected incompatibilities, irreproducible builds, etc.)

On your main `build.gradle` file define a constant:

```
allprojects {

    ext {
        global_version_firebase = '16.0.+'
    }
}
```

And use it like `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$global_version_firebase"`

And some version differences on firebase and play services are [actually major changes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) (i.e.: `firebase-core:16.0.4` and `firebase-ads:17.1.0`), so the convenient `+` on the minor version would not work for all cases, and you would need to put the `+` on the whole version number, which is a no-go.